# Node include upload.js gives me a ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

Tags: node.js, node-modules

I'm new using node.js.

I'd like to call another.js when server page is /signup

So I have my server.js:

```
const http = require('http')
const port = 80
const ip = 'localhost'

const server = http.createServer((req, res) => {
  if (req.url == '/') {
    res.end('<h1>Home</h1>');
  }

  else if (req.url == '/signup') {
    require('./upload.js');
  }
})

server.listen(port, ip, () => {
  console.log(`running http://${ip}:${port}`)
  console.log('Press ctrl + c to stop');
})
```

and the upload.js:

```
var formidable = require('formidable');
var fs = require('fs');


  if (req.url == '/fileupload') {
    var form = new formidable.IncomingForm();
    form.parse(req, function (err, fields, files) {
      var oldpath = files.filetoupload.path;
      var newpath = '/' + files.filetoupload.name;
      fs.rename(oldpath, newpath, function (err) {
        if (err) throw err;
        res.write('File uploaded and moved!');
        res.end();
      });
 });
  } 
  else {
    res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
    res.write('<form action="fileupload" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">');
    res.write('<input type="file" name="filetoupload"><br>');
    res.write('<input type="submit">');
    res.write('</form>');
    return res.end();
  }
```

The problem is /signup is giving ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED.

What is wrong? any ideas?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the way you are thinking about nodeJs require. You do not require files to call/execute that file (although they do get executed). You require it to include the functions of another file in your current file. Then you execute the functions that you required. Much like #include in C. I would urge you to read [this](https://nodejs.org/en/knowledge/getting-started/what-is-require/) to understand how it all works in nodejs.

Also you must understand the concept of asynchronous programming in nodejs, if you haven't read about it already - https://blog.risingstack.com/node-hero-async-programming-in-node-js/